# Python large file nested line JSON to CSV file extracting only specific key value pairs

Tags: python, json, csv, twitter

Hi I am looking for some help parsing Twitter line JSON data to python dictionaries and extracting to smaller CSV files using Python 3.8.5. The Twitter data has already been collected and saved into several gzip files that are approx 450Mb compressed and >2.7Gb uncompressed. Each file contains approx 800,000 lines. All the JSON files contain all the twitter objects. I only want to extract certain key : values as I do not need all the data. However I'm having difficulties extracting those specific keys as some are nested. Not all keys contain values in this case I would like to return 'Null'/'None'. All other posts and YouTube videos deal with simple files or extract all keys.

**I have managed to parse the JSON data to python dictionary line by line (note I have found ujson works better for memory load and speed):**

```
import gzip
import json
import ujson
import csv

tweets = []
with gzip.open('small_test_file.gz', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        tweets.append(ujson.loads(line)) 
    
print("Finished processing: " + str(len(tweets)) + " lines")

infile.close()
```

**These are the keys/columns I would like:**

```
header = ['id', 'created_at', 'screen_name', 'text', 'lang', 'place.country_code', 'place.name', 'coordinates_long', 'coordinates_lat']
```

**This is the csv.DictWriter code I'm using:**

```
with open('clean_test_long.csv', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as outfile:    # opens outfile as json

    header = ['id', 'created_at', 'screen_name', 'text', 'lang', 'place.country_code', 'place.name', 'coordinates_long', 'coordinates_lat']
    
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames ='header', restval = None)


    csv_writer.writeheader()    # write header row using filednames

    for tweet in tweets:    

        csv_writer.writerow(tweet['id'],
        tweet['created_at'],
        tweet['user']['screen_name'],
        tweet['text'],
        tweet['lang'],
        tweet['place']['country_code'],
        tweet['place']['name'],
        tweet['coordinates']['coordinates'][0],
        tweet['coordinates']['coordinates'][1])

outfile.close()
```

**I get the following error:**

```
    tweet['coordinates']['coordinates'][0],
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I have also tried using .get 'tweet.get('coordinates').get('coordinates')[0]' on all objects to replace missing values but that doesn't work.

I have also tried pandas json.normalize but again this doesn't flatten the structure beyond top level and takes a dump on the massive gzip files which is why I was hoping to clean it first before doing my analysis with pandas.

**An example of the data lines:**

```
[
{
"truncated": false,
"contributors": null,
"place": null,
"reply_count": 0,
"retweeted": false,
"in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
"source": "",
"in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
"id": 1233904784635256833,
"retweet_count": 0,
"filter_level": "low",
"user": {
    "profile_background_image_url": "",
    "profile_text_color": "333333",
    "profile_background_tile": false,
    "profile_background_image_url_https": "",
    "profile_image_url_https": "",
    "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",
    "url": null,
    "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
    "location": null,
    "default_profile": true,
    "listed_count": 65,
    "id": 1092190045,
    "statuses_count": 62340,
    "translator_type": "none",
    "profile_image_url": "",
    "is_translator": false,
    "id_str": "1092190045",
    "time_zone": null,
    "friends_count": 24,
    "profile_banner_url": "",
    "favourites_count": 25,
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
    "description": null,
    "protected": false,
    "contributors_enabled": false,
    "lang": null,
    "name": "Rathausuhr Neuk\u00f6lln",
    "notifications": null,
    "following": null,
    "created_at": "Tue Jan 15 14:06:09 +0000 2013",
    "profile_use_background_image": true,
    "utc_offset": null,
    "follow_request_sent": null,
    "screen_name": "rh_neukoelln",
    "verified": false,
    "geo_enabled": true,
    "default_profile_image": false,
    "profile_link_color": "1DA1F2",
    "followers_count": 1653
},
"id_str": "1233904784635256833",
"in_reply_to_user_id": null,
"in_reply_to_status_id": null,
"lang": "de",
"favorited": false,
"favorite_count": 0,
"entities": {
    "symbols": [],
    "hashtags": [],
    "urls": [],
    "user_mentions": []
},
"coordinates": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
        13.435,
        52.481388
    ]
},
"in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
"created_at": "Sun Mar 01 00:00:00 +0000 2020",
"timestamp_ms": "1583020800156",
"text": "schepper",
"quote_count": 0,
"geo": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
        52.481388,
        13.435
    ]
},
"is_quote_status": false
},
{
"truncated": false,
"contributors": null,
"place": {
    "attributes": {},
    "bounding_box": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    -7.017507,
                    52.122381
                ],
                [
                    -7.017507,
                    52.797086
                ],
                [
                    -6.141269,
                    52.797086
                ],
                [
                    -6.141269,
                    52.122381
                ]
            ]
        ]
    },
    "full_name": "Wexford, Ireland",
    "url": "",
    "name": "Wexford",
    "country_code": "IE",
    "id": "0239f5fd632185d5",
    "country": "Ireland",
    "place_type": "city"
},
"in_reply_to_status_id": null,
"retweeted": false,
"in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
"source": "",
"in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
"quoted_status": {
    "display_text_range": [
        0,
        53
    ],
    "truncated": false,
    "place": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "retweeted": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "source": "",
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "id": 1233902879301349379,
    "retweet_count": 40,
    "filter_level": "low",
    "user": {
        "profile_background_image_url": "",
        "profile_text_color": "000000",
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "",
        "profile_image_url_https": "",
        "profile_background_color": "000000",
        "url": "",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "000000",
        "location": "NYC",
        "default_profile": false,
        "listed_count": 616,
        "id": 249547283,
        "statuses_count": 51127,
        "translator_type": "none",
        "profile_image_url": "",
        "is_translator": false,
        "id_str": "249547283",
        "time_zone": null,
        "friends_count": 1187,
        "profile_banner_url": "",
        "favourites_count": 88876,
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "000000",
        "description": "Host of the Michael Brooks Show, join: @tmbsfm Contributor/producer, @Majorityfm Co-host Woke Bros. Member of the Yacubian Left",
        "protected": false,
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "lang": null,
        "name": "Michael Brooks",
        "notifications": null,
        "following": null,
        "created_at": "Wed Feb 09 08:13:53 +0000 2011",
        "profile_use_background_image": false,
        "utc_offset": null,
        "follow_request_sent": null,
        "screen_name": "_michaelbrooks",
        "verified": false,
        "geo_enabled": true,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "profile_link_color": "0065B3",
        "followers_count": 79224
    },
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "lang": "en",
    "id_str": "1233902879301349379",
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "quoted_status_id": 1233899739906813952,
    "reply_count": 35,
    "quoted_status_id_str": "1233899739906813952",
    "favorited": false,
    "favorite_count": 423,
    "entities": {
        "symbols": [],
        "hashtags": [],
        "urls": [
            {
                "indices": [
                    54,
                    77
                ],
                "expanded_url": "",
                "display_url": "",
                "url": ""
            }
        ],
        "user_mentions": []
    },
    "coordinates": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "created_at": "Sat Feb 29 23:52:25 +0000 2020",
    "text": "Are they genuinely nuts enough to think they can win? ",
    "quote_count": 1,
    "geo": null,
    "is_quote_status": true
},
```

Answer (score 0):

you could simply try and catch the exception (which means the coordinates are null-valued) or even use an if statement to check if the coordinates key has a corresponding value and is not of value None

Answer (score 0):

You might use the following basic workarounds:

- **Using Try-Catch:**

```
try:
      coordinates = tweet['coordinates']['coordinates'][0]

except:
      coordinates = None
```

- **Check the existence of parameters**

```
if 'coordinates' in tweet and 'coordinates' in tweet['coordinates'] and len(tweet['coordinates']['coordinates']) > 0: 
      coordinates = tweet['coordinates']['coordinates'][0]
```

I prefer using the first solution, it would be processed faster.

Comment: Thank you. I've placed the try and except statement before the writerow but get the same error, 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable - coordinates_long = tweet['coordinates']['coordinates'][0],